# Cannot go on $x\equiv y \pmod 4$

Tags: combinatorics

A particle can move from $(x,y)$ to $(x+1,y)$ or $(x,y+1)$, but it cannot go onto any point $(x,y)$ such that both $x$ and $y$ have the same nonzero residue modulo $4$ (in particular, it can go on points in which both coordinates are multiples of $4$). How many paths can it take from $(0,0)$ to $(40,40)$? (And in general, to any point of the form $(4k,4k)$?)

---

I tried a generating functions approach at first, but while a generating function can keep track of the end result it can't really keep track of states in between. Then I've tried letting $f(a,b)$ be the number of ways to the point $(a,b)$ and did something like:
$$\begin{align*}
f(40,40) &= f(39, 40) + f(40,39) = 2f(39,40)\\
&=2[f(38,40)+f(39,39)] = 2[f(38,40)]\\
&=2[f(37, 40) + f(38,39)]\\
&=2[f(36,40) + f(37,39) + f(37,39) + f(38,38)] = 2[f(36,40) + 2[f(37,39)]]
\end{align*}$$
which I don't see simplifying nicely because the $(4m, 4n)$ type points don't disappear. I've also tried drawing the grid and seeing the numbers for $(4,4)$ and $(8,8)$ but I can't see a pattern, and I've thought about splitting the grid into $4\times 4$ grids because of modulo $4$, but I'm unsure of how to use that.

Comment: I suggest working  this out for small $k$ to see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Yeah I did and for $k=1$ i got $10$ and for $k=2$ i got $330$ (assuming I did it right), which I don't see a pattern in.

Comment: What is the starting point? (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll add it.

Comment: I agree with the recursive approach, but it doesn't seem clear to me that it will give a useful general formula.  Of course, you could program it readily enough and for modest numbers that should suffice.

Comment: Yeah I guess you could but I intend to solve it mathematically. The problem with a recursion is that are too may states, I feel.

Comment: Use backwards induction.  There's only one path from $(39,40)$, and so on.  The computation should not be bad.  There may, of course, be a sensible closed form but I am skeptical.

Comment: But isn't that what I've done above with the $f$'s?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what you mean about states.  In each case $f(m,n)=f(m+1,n)+f(m,n+1)$.  No problem keeping track of that in a modest array (and $40\times 40$ is pretty small, really).

Comment: If nothing else, the program should let you solve the problem for $(4k,4k)$ for many small $k$.  Then you could search [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) to see if the sequence is known, or try to analyze it directly.  If there is a sensible closed formula, this should help to discover it.  Also:  you'll need several known values to test any general formula or methodology.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it for some smaller $k$

Comment: No, as I mentioned in the problem statement the particle can go to points where both coordinates are divisible by $4$.

Comment: I wrote some python code, the number of paths to (4k,4k) for k=0,1,2,3,4,5,... is 1, 10, 310, 9,860, 319,910, 10,540,460, ...

Comment: It is roughly exponential, which makes sense for a recurrence

Comment: .... 351,475,260

Comment: It's pretty easy to set this up in Excel. I got the same values as Joshua. Doesn't seem to be a pattern to me.  Leaving it to OP to find the number of paths to (40,40).  $\quad$ Note that the mod 2 version has a nice pattern, which makes sense when you look at it. However, it doesn't extend to mod 3 or mod 4.

Comment: @lulu see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=4k+i$ and $y=4l+j$ be the general coordinates, where $(i,j)=(1,1)$,
$(i,j)=(2,2)$ and $(i,j)=(3,3)$ are not accessible. Let $S_{k,l,i,j}$ be
the number of steps to reach one square with $S_{0,0,0,0}=1$ as the
starting position, $S_{k,l,1,1}=S_{k,l,2,2}=S_{k,l,3,3}=0$ the inaccessible
squares. Recurrences for right and up steps of the 16 squares are:
\begin{multline}
S_{k,l,0,0} = S_{k-1,l,3,0}+S_{k,l-1,0,3} ;\\
S_{k,l,1,0} = S_{k,l,0,0} + S_{k,l-1,1,3} ;\\
S_{k,l,2,0} = S_{k,l,1,0} + S_{k,l-1,2,3} ;\\
S_{k,l,3,0} = S_{k,l,2,0}  ;\\
S_{k,l,0,1} = S_{k-1,l,3,1}+S_{k,l,0,0} ;\\
S_{k,l,1,1} =  0 ;\\
S_{k,l,2,1} = S_{k,l,2,0}  ;\\
S_{k,l,3,1} = S_{k,l,2,1} + S_{k,l,3,0} ;\\
S_{k,l,0,2} = S_{k-1,l,3,2}+S_{k,l,0,1} ;\\
S_{k,l,1,2} = S_{k,l,0,2} ;\\
S_{k,l,2,2} =  0 ;\\
S_{k,l,3,2} = S_{k,l,3,1} ;\\
S_{k,l,0,3} = S_{k,l,0,2} ;\\
S_{k,l,1,3} = S_{k,l,0,3} + S_{k,l,1,2} ;\\
S_{k,l,2,3} = S_{k,l,1,3} ;\\
S_{k,l,3,3} =  0 ;
\end{multline}
The bivariate generating function is $S_{i,j}(u,v)\equiv \sum_{k,l\ge0 } S_{k,l,i,j} u^kv^l$, so
\begin{multline}
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,0} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k-1,l,3,0}u^kv^l +\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l-1,0,3} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,0} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,0} u^kv^l + \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l-1,1,3} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,0} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,0} u^kv^l + \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l-1,2,3} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,3,0} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,0} u^kv^l ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,1} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k-1,l,3,1}u^kv^l +\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,0} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,1} =  0 ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,1} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,0} u^kv^l  ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,3,1} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,1} u^kv^l + \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,3,0} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,2} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k-1,l,3,2}u^kv^l +\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,1} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,2} = \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,2} u^kv^l ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,2} =  0 ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,3,2} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,3,1} u^kv^l ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,3} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,2} u^kv^l ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,3} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,0,3} u^kv^l + \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,2} u^kv^l;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,2,3} u^kv^l= \sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,1,3} u^kv^l ;\\
\sum_{k,l} S_{k,l,3,3} =  0 .
\end{multline}
\begin{multline}
S_{0,0}(u,v)= u S_{3,0}(u,v) + v S_{0,3}(u,v) ;\\
S_{1,0}(u,v)= S_{0,0}(u,v) + v S_{1,3}(u,v) ;\\
S_{2,0}(u,v)= S_{1,0}(u,v) + v S_{2,3}(u,v) ;\\
S_{3,0}(u,v)= S_{2,0}(u,v) ;\\
S_{0,1}(u,v)= u S_{3,1}(u,v) + S_{0,0}(u,v);\\
S_{1,1}(u,v) =  0 ;\\
S_{2,1}(u,v)= S_{2,0}(u,v);\\
S_{3,1}(u,v)= S_{2,1}(u,v) + S_{3,0}(u,v) ;\\
S_{0,2}(u,v)= u S_{3,2}(u,v) + S_{0,1}(u,v) ;\\
S_{1,2}(u,v) = S_{0,2}(u,v) ;\\
S_{2,2}(u,v) =  0 ;\\
S_{3,2}(u,v)= S_{3,1}(u,v) ;\\
S_{0,3}(u,v)= S_{0,2}(u,v) ;\\
S_{1,3}(u,v)= S_{0,3}(u,v) + S_{1,2}(u,v) ;\\
S_{2,3}(u,v)= S_{1,3}(u,v) ;\\
S_{3,3}(u,v) =  0 .
\end{multline}
Elimination of some cases where the right hand sides contain only one term:
\begin{multline}
S_{0,0}(u,v)= u S_{2,0}(u,v) + v S_{0,2}(u,v) ;\\
S_{1,0}(u,v)= S_{0,0}(u,v) + v S_{1,3}(u,v) ;\\
S_{2,0}(u,v)= S_{1,0}(u,v) + v S_{1,3}(u,v) ;\\
S_{0,1}(u,v)= u S_{3,1}(u,v) + S_{0,0}(u,v);\\
S_{3,1}(u,v)= S_{2,0}(u,v) + S_{2,0}(u,v) ;\\
S_{0,2}(u,v)= u S_{3,1}(u,v) + S_{0,1}(u,v) ;\\
S_{1,3}(u,v)= S_{0,2}(u,v) + S_{0,2}(u,v) ;
\end{multline}

In summary this is a linear system of equations, omitting the arguments $(u,v)$ for brevity:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
S_{0,0}\\
S_{1,0}\\
S_{2,0}\\
S_{0,1}\\
S_{3,1}\\
S_{0,2}\\
S_{1,3}\\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
0 & 0 & u &  0 & 0 &v &0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 &0 &v \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 &0 &v \\
1 & 0 & 0 &  0 & u &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 &  0 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & u &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 &2 &0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
S_{0,0}\\
S_{1,0}\\
S_{2,0}\\
S_{0,1}\\
S_{3,1}\\
S_{0,2}\\
S_{1,3}\\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
This equation has the format $\vec S^{(n+1)}=X \vec S^{(n)}$, where the initial iteration
(lowest order) is $S_{0,0}(u,v)=1$ and all other $S_{i,j}(u,v)=0$.
Applying the transfer matrix methods means to re-insert the right hand
side iteratively, so the matrix on the right hand side is effectively
replaced by the sum of its $n$-th powers, $\vec S=\sum_{n\ge 0} X^n \vec S^{(0)}=(1-X)^{-1}\vec S^{(0)}$. So one needs the inverse of $1-X$, and to multiply the
vector $S^{(0)}$ from the right:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
S_{0,0}\\
S_{1,0}\\
S_{2,0}\\
S_{0,1}\\
S_{3,1}\\
S_{0,2}\\
S_{1,3}\\
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
1 & 0 & -u & 0 & 0 &-v &0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &-v \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 &-v \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -u &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 1 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -u &1 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-2 &1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
Because only the top entry $S(0,0)(u,v)$ is nonzero, the only relevant
column of the inverse matrix is the leftmost column:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
S_{0,0}\\
S_{1,0}\\
S_{2,0}\\
S_{3,0}\\
S_{0,1}\\
S_{3,1}\\
S_{0,2}\\
S_{1,3}\\
\end{array}
\right)=
\frac{1}{-1+u+v+24uv}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
-1+16uv & \ldots & \ldots \\
-1-2v+8uv & \ldots & \ldots\\
-1-4v & \ldots & \ldots\\
-1-2u+8uv & \ldots & \ldots\\
-2(1+4v) & \ldots & \ldots\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
In particular
$S_{0,0}=\frac{1-16uv}{1-v-u-24uv}
=1+v+u+u^2+10uv+v^2+u^3+35u^2v+35uv^2+v^3+\cdots 310 u^2v^2+\cdots 469626782869460 u^{10}v^{10}+
\cdots= (1-16uv)\sum_{t\ge 0 } (v+u+24uv)^t$.
Contribution to the central coefficient $[(uv)^i]S_{0,0}(u,v)$ are nonzero only
if $s$ is even:
\begin{multline}
S_{0,0}(u,v)
=
(1-16uv)\sum_{t\ge 0 }\sum_{s=0,2,4,\ldots}^t \binom{t}{s} \binom{s}{s/2}(vu)^{s/2} (24uv)^{t-s}+\cdots
=\\
(1-16uv)\sum_{t\ge 0 }\sum_{s=0}^{t/2} \binom{t}{2s} \binom{2s}{s} 24^{t-2s}(uv)^{t-s}+\cdots\\
=(1-16uv)\sum_{t\ge 0 }\sum_{s=0}^{t/2} \frac{t!}{(t-2s)!s!s!} 24^{t-2s}(uv)^{t-s}+\cdots\\
=(1-16uv)\sum_{t-s\ge 0 }\sum_{s=0}^{t-s} \frac{t!}{(t-s-s)!s!s!} 24^{t-2s}(uv)^{t-s}+\cdots\\
=(1-16uv)\sum_{k\ge 0 }(uv)^k\sum_{s=0}^{k} \frac{(k+s)!}{(k-s)!s!s!}24^{k-s} +\cdots\\
\end{multline}

Answer (score 2):

The number of paths to $(4k,4k)$ for $k\ge0$ is
$$1,10,310,9860,319910,\dots$$
From Mathar's answer, which shows the bivariate generating function to be $\frac{1-16uv}{1-u-v-24uv}$, we can get the generating function for the diagonal through a residue method (6.3.5 in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Volume II). First substitute $v=u/x$ and divide by $u$ to get
$$g(u)=\frac{1-16x}{u(1-u-24x)-x}$$
Then the diagonal generating function is $\sum_p\operatorname{Res}_pg(u)$ where $p$ ranges over all poles of $g$ that approach $0$ as $x\to0$. In this case the only such pole is the simple $q=\frac{1-24x-\sqrt{(1-16x)(1-36x)}}2$, so we compute the desired function as
$$\frac{1-16x}{\frac d{du}u(1-u-24x)|_{u=q}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-16x}{1-36x}}$$
The coefficient of the $x^{10}$ term of its expansion gives the desired answer $469626782869460$.

Comment: Well!  Surprisingly simple, in some ways.  That ought to have a combinatorial meaning, but damned if I can spot one.

Comment: Ah, the revised answer is even better.

Comment: The sequence $a_n=1,10,310,9860,319910,\ldots$, $n\ge 0$ ,has the recurrence $na_n+2(21-16n)a_{n-1}+576(n-1)a_{n-2}=0$, obtained as detailed in  https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.02112 . This is about the fastest numerical way to expand $\sqrt{(1-16x)/(1-36x)}$